# When I click on a button, the external CSS does not work but inline CSS does work

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem I am facing is that when I click on the add button ( + ), all the CSS styling stops working (whatever's there in the CSS stylesheet). So I started using inline CSS in the JavaScript file (" ") because this same thing in CSS was not working. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem and make it work in an external stylesheet?

Ok, so here's my HTML Code:
(file name = 'index_button.html')

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Calculator </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style_button.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="./index_button.js"> </script>
        <button type="button" onclick="button0Clicked();"> 0 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button1Clicked();"> 1 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button2Clicked();"> 2 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button3Clicked();"> 3 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button4Clicked();"> 4 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button5Clicked();"> 5 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button6Clicked();"> 6 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button7Clicked();"> 7 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button8Clicked();"> 8 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button9Clicked();"> 9 </button>
        <div class='text'> First Number </div>

        <br> <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="button0ClickedAdd();"> 0 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button1ClickedAdd();"> 1 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button2ClickedAdd();"> 2 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button3ClickedAdd();"> 3 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button4ClickedAdd();"> 4 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button5ClickedAdd();"> 5 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button6ClickedAdd();"> 6 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button7ClickedAdd();"> 7 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button8ClickedAdd();"> 8 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button9ClickedAdd();"> 9 </button>
        <div class='text'> Second Number </div>

        <br> <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="add();"> + </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

then, here is my CSS stylesheet:
(file name = 'style_button.css')

```
html {
    background-color: black;
}

.number {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.text {
    color: white;
}
```

and here's my JavaScript:
(file name = 'index_button.js)

```
let number;
let number2;
let result;

function button0Clicked() {
    number = 0;
}
function button1Clicked() {
    number = 1;
}
function button2Clicked() {
    number = 2;
}
function button3Clicked() {
    number = 3;
}
function button4Clicked() {
    number = 4;
}
function button5Clicked() {
    number = 5;
}
function button6Clicked() {
    number = 6;
}
function button7Clicked() {
    number = 7;
}
function button8Clicked() {
    number = 8;
}
function button9Clicked() {
    number = 9;
}

function button0ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 0;
}
function button1ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 1;
}
function button2ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 2;
}
function button3ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 3;
}
function button4ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 4;
}
function button5ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 5;
}
function button6ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 6;
}
function button7ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 7;
}
function button8ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 8;
}
function button9ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 9;
}

function add() {
    result = number + number2;
    document.write("<font color='white' size='200%'> <body bgcolor='black'>" + result);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the browser's console for any errors?

Comment: `document.write` will clear the entire document and replace it with what you pass into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. Only some small mistakes and potential. Assign a value to your declared vars `number, etc` Then i wrap you section inner container. After clicked Add i can select the container add apply then new class green. What stands for success.

```js
let number = null;
let number2 = null;
let result = 0;

function button0Clicked() {
    number = 0;
}
function button1Clicked() {
    number = 1;
}
function button2Clicked() {
    number = 2;
}
function button3Clicked() {
    number = 3;
}
function button4Clicked() {
    number = 4;
}
function button5Clicked() {
    number = 5;
}
function button6Clicked() {
    number = 6;
}
function button7Clicked() {
    number = 7;
}
function button8Clicked() {
    number = 8;
}
function button9Clicked() {
    number = 9;
}

function button0ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 0;
}
function button1ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 1;
}
function button2ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 2;
}
function button3ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 3;
}
function button4ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 4;
}
function button5ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 5;
}
function button6ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 6;
}
function button7ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 7;
}
function button8ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 8;
}
function button9ClickedAdd() {
    number2 = 9;
}

function add() {
  if(number === null || number2 === null) {
    console.log('first click numbers!')
    return false;
  }
    result = number + number2;
    let c = document.querySelector('.container')
    c.classList.add('green')
    c.innerHTML = 'Result:' + result;

}
```

```css
html {
    background-color: black;
}

.number {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.text {
    color: white;
}
.container {
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.green {  
  background: green;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <script src="./index_button.js"> </script>
        <button type="button" onclick="button0Clicked();"> 0 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button1Clicked();"> 1 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button2Clicked();"> 2 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button3Clicked();"> 3 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button4Clicked();"> 4 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button5Clicked();"> 5 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button6Clicked();"> 6 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button7Clicked();"> 7 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button8Clicked();"> 8 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button9Clicked();"> 9 </button>
        <div class='text'> First Number </div>

        <br> <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="button0ClickedAdd();"> 0 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button1ClickedAdd();"> 1 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button2ClickedAdd();"> 2 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button3ClickedAdd();"> 3 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button4ClickedAdd();"> 4 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button5ClickedAdd();"> 5 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button6ClickedAdd();"> 6 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button7ClickedAdd();"> 7 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button8ClickedAdd();"> 8 </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="button9ClickedAdd();"> 9 </button>
        <div class='text'> Second Number </div>

        <br> <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="add();"> + </button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Ok so I tried out your code and the console gives me this error when I click on the two buttons for the numbers and then the add button:

index_button.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at add (index_button.js:74:7)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:38:52)

Comment: @ATcrafts I would guess that you have not added the wrapper class .container to your code. Have a look at my code example. It works. So wrap your code in `<div class="container"> ...your html ...</div>`.